# "У відповідності з" чи "відповідно до"?

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами, прийменники

Зустрічала як варіант вживання "у відповідності з", так і "відповідно до".

Наприклад, на сторінці [Економічного наукового клубу](https://www.facebook.com/economscienclub/posts/2054801744534554) є таке:

> **У відповідності з** рішенням Ректорату Університету заняття для
>   студентів припиняються на період з 5 по 7 березня 2018 року.

А от на [Офіційному сайті Верховного Суду України](http://www.scourt.gov.ua/clients/vsu/vsu.nsf/(documents)/EF1A5FE2991C83A3C2257AF4003ABD34?OpenDocument) міститься інше:

> **Відповідно до** Закону України «Про внесення змін до деяких законодавчих
>   актів України щодо регулювання ринку автомобілів в Україні»
>   автомобіль...  .

Таким чином, обидва варіанти вживаються майже в однаковому контексті.

*То як розрізняти, коли потрібно використовувати "відповідно до", а коли "у відповідності з"?*

Comment: Родич-запитання: [Згідно з чим **згідно чому** є неправильним узгодженням іменника з прийменником?](/q/1508/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сайті [Оnline corrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE/) пише:

> Замініть нехарактерну для української мови конструкцію **у відповідності до** (чогось) на стилістично кращий варіант: **відповідно до (чогось)**.

Таким чином конструкція "у відповідності до" є *не рекомендованою* (!!!) для використання. Однак конструкцію *у відповідності з* не згадано взагалі.

Дещо іншу інформацію бачимо і на лінгвістичному порталі [MOVA.info](http://www.mova.info/article.aspx?l1=114&DID=340):

> Прийменник **відповідно** вживається з родовим відмінком іменника у сполученні з прийменником **до**: відповідно до наказу, відповідно до змін, відповідно до програми.
>
> Увага! Прийменникової сполуки ***у відповідності*** в українській літературній мові немає - це *калька з російського* **в соответствии**.

На сайті [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/zgidno-z-i-vidpovidno-do) теж повідомляють, що:

> «Згідно інструкції», «відповідно з …», *«у відповідності з …»*, «згідно до…» – це все помилкові конструкції. Українською потрібно говорити: **«відповідно до …» і «згідно з …»**.

У [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53399/25787.html) вже розгорнутіше читаємо:

> Форми іменників із прийменниками згідно з та відповідно до характерні для офіційно-ділового, наукового стилів. Буває, що згідно помилково сполучають з давальним або родовим відмінком: згідно повір’ю, згідно планів, згідно рішення, згідно протоколу. ***Ці утворення – наслідок впливу граматичної системи російської мови***: согласно поверью, согласно планам. Треба: згідно з рішенням, згідно з протоколом. Неправильні конструкції типу відповідно з планами і згідно до планів. Не відповідає сучасній літературній нормі також форма іменників з прийменником *у відповідності з* (*калька з російської мови* в соответствии с).

*Отже, ми маємо використовувати **лише** СТАЛІ конструкції згідно з, **відповідно до**. Конструкція у відповідності з вважається калькою з російської мови.*

Answer (score -1):

Ще можна казати *за*:

> Кожен стіл співає пісні в порядку черги за номером столу.

> Особисті дані клієнтів зберігають та охороняють за найвищими світовими стандартами.

Comment: "В порядку черги" - це хіба не канцеляризм? "стіл співає"? Здається так ще гірше виходить. До того ж наведені конкретні приклади, як вашу пропозицію застосувати до них? Поки що ваш пост не відповідає на питання автора. Зауважте, що за правилами цього сайту відповідь потрібно обґрунтувати за допомогою посилання на авторитетні джерела, інакше її буде видалено.

Comment: "в порядку черги"  і "стіл співає" там через те, що приклади з context reverso.

Comment: у відповідності/відповідно — калька, як і інші прийменники, що походять від іменників. І чи на це треба джерела?

Comment: Відповідно, згідно — такі самі кальки, вони не кращі, зрозумійте

Comment: Те, що в деяких випадках можна казати просто «за», — це, по-моєму, доволі корисне нагадування. (Щодо джерел, то, по-перше, про це каже 12-те значення [слова «за» в словнику](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=27400&page=918), по-друге, схожі (на мій погляд) приклади [наводив Пономарів](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2014/02/140204_ponomariv_blog9_ko): «за інструкціями», «сортувати за алфавітом/абеткою», «впорядковувати за змістом», «розташовувати за нумерацією», «викликати за чергою». То чому б не «за таким-то законом, автомобіль…»?)

Comment: Але от твердження, мовляв, варіант із «за» — єдиний притомний (а решта — канцеляризми), обґрунтувати значно важче. Так, на нього (на твердження, що «відповідно до», «у відповідності з», «згідно з» і загалом прийменники, які походять від іменників, — усе це кальки) варто все-таки подати бодай якісь джерела. Може, поки їх немає, спробувати переформулювати відповідь на лише нагадування, мовляв, є ще гарний варіант із «за» (але без категоричних заяв про решту варіантів)?

Comment: (Off-topic: І знати б ще, де проходить ота межа… Я маю на увазі: між «добрим» терміном (що може звучати сухо, але дозволяє розрізнити важливі нюанси, точний) і «поганим» канцеляризмом (що лише ускладнює читання).)

Comment: "приклади з context reverso" - хоча там є і корисні приклади, але я бачив там досить химерні варіанти. Схоже що більшість прикладів зроблена шляхом автоматичного перекладу і деякі варіанти просто жахливі. Я б не радив вживати приклади з цього сайту без додаткової перевірки. Сайт дозволяє користувачам пропонувати виправлення і можливо це його робить до певної міри корисним. Але пошук на сайті менш вживаної лексики видає досить неадекватні варіанти, мабуть через те що туди живі люди ще не заглядали.

Comment: Згідний, я там сам виправляю й виправляю все...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/4069)